# SharePoint Server 2016 customizable AppLauncher troubleshooting help

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, applauncher

In one of the SP2016 feature packs they added the ability to add custom tiles to the AppLauncher, getting it going is decently documented here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790697(v=office.16)

One thing that isn't clear to me and that I learned through troubleshooting is I had an issue where most of the users if not all didn't see the custom tiles that got added. This was after both using the `ClearSuiteLinksCache()` function in browser and waiting 24 hours.

I tried a couple of things, like granting everyone read-only access to the applauncher and images libraries in central administration (but obviously not publishing links via email to the libraries). I assumed the reason people didn't see the links was because they didn't have permissions. I actually am not able to confirm at all if this is the fix because I saw inconsistent behavior across peoples machines.

Does anyone know what the exact requirements are for getting the tiles to definitely show up across site collections in a separate web application from central admin? Assume that I've followed all of the steps in the MSDN article correctly.